# In yii 1.1.x move all forms in new /protected/forms/ directory

Tags: php, forms, yii

In all yii 1.1 examples I see that forms are kept in /protected/models/ subdirectory.
I want to move all forms in new /protected/forms/ directory. which is the safe way of this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just move models in this subdirectory and add to `import` in config (main.php) this line:

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.forms.*',
    ...
)
```